# 'ViewBag' It may be inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

MVC 5 vb web application
I created a entityFramework migrations where I have a class library for data entities and combined it with the AspNet Identity within the web application. No error so far. I created a IndentityDB that has the defaultConnection and updated the AccountController to point to the connection
`(New UserStore(Of ApplicationUser)(New IndentityDB())))`

seems to be right with no error on the build except for a enum issue in the classlibrary that I will fix later but I get a error:

```
'ViewBag' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
```

> A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in System.dll A first chance exception of type
>   'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.dll 'iisexpress.exe'
>   (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/32/ROOT-1-130360312907627858): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.Services.Design\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.Services.Design.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file.

This error happens when I try to login on the home page and any other Authorized Controller